# Java EE:links to learn JBoss/EJB and JMS

Tags: java, jms, ejb-3.0, ejb

I'm a core Java developer and now interested to learn EJB and JMS.

Could anyone give me links to learn those from scratch? I mean I need a basic introduction to start with Java EE technologies. I also need to use the JBoss server and a Swing client for development. Please point me to useful links related to this too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148491/any-good-resource-for-learning-both-jee-and-j2ee-simultaneously

Comment: A small comment: the term is now Java EE, not J2EE. J2EE now refers to version 1.4 and earlier. Believe me, you don't want to learn those ;)

Answer (score 2):

- http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/firstcup/doc/
- [Official Java EE 5 tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/)
- [Real World Java EE Patterns Rethinking Best Practices](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0557078326)